# Собрать данные из нескольких вложенных subscribe в Angular2+

Tags: angular2, angular4, rxjs

Есть обращение к сереру, его слушает subscribe, затем который возвращает обьект из которого достается массив данных с номерами заказа. По этим номерам заказов следом делаю запросы в цикле, подписываюсь на них и пушу в общий массив.

```
let collect = [];

this.service.getData(url1).subscribe(
    res = > { // Возвращает: {Object:[{key:number},{key:number}]}
            orderArray = [];
            for (let items of res.Object) {
                orderArray.push(items.key);
            }

        if(orderArray) {
            for (let i = 0; i < orderArray.length; i++) {
                this.service.getData(otherUrl).subscribe(
                    res2 = > { // {item: 'имя'}
                        collect.push(res2.item)
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Проблема в том, что не могу использовать collect дальше т.к. он пустой...
Как собрать данные?

Comment: структурируйте ваш код и покажите настоящий пример, я вижу что вы в цикле делаете запрос на один и тот же url

Comment: Да, сорри, спешил. Урл разные, код подправил

Comment: а что у вас в `res`? в смысле - массив пользователей, todos, или еще что-то? и зачем в цикле делать запросы на один и тот же урл `url2`? просто поправьте эту семантику, мне так легче будет дать вам ответ

Comment: res возвращает массив номеров заказов, которые нужно послать в запросе на otherUrl, чтобы получить имя. Имя нужно запушить в общий массив. Поправил в коде

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `pipeable` операторы и избегайте подписок внутри подписок:

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const collect = [];

this.service.getData(url).pipe(
    map((res) => res.Object.map((order) => order.key)),
    filter((orders) => !!orders.length),
    switchMap((orders) => forkJoin(
        ...orders.map((order) => this.service.getData(otherUrl))
    ).pipe(
        tap((collectedData) => collect.push(...collectedData))
    ))
).subscribe(() => {
    console.log(collect);
});
```

Comment: Я понимаю, что subscribe в subscribe неправильно, но понимал как уйти от этого. Спасибо, попробую сейчас

Comment: А что попадает в orders в filter((orders)?

Comment: поток сгенерирует событие если длина `orders` больше 0, как раз то что выделали с помощью `if (res)`

Comment: Понял, а как можно обработать предварительно данные которые попадают в orders? Мне туда сложный обьект приходит

Comment: вы хотите сделать что-то перед циклом запросов?

Comment: Да, обработать обьект и в зависимости есть ли в нем нужные данные выслать новый запрос

Comment: исправьте ваш вопрос как вы хотите чтоб это выглядело

Comment: Поправил вопрос

Comment: @Lex, изменил ответ

Comment: Спасибо, у меня ошибок куча, буду разбираться